# EF SqlQuery with navigation properties

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, navigation-properties

I want call sp in t-sql from EF 6. At the same time i want load data to navigation property. On sql server side my SP Joins 2 table and returns. But EF side dont bind navigation properties.

My query code loads car data but when i want reach Engine.Name it comes null. How can i fill it ?

```
//query code
_context.Cars.SqlQuery("select * from Car join Engine on Cars.EngineID = Engine.EngineID")

//sample code
public class Car
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int EngineID { get; set; }
    public virtual Engine CarEngine { get; set; }
}

public class Engine
{
    public int EngineID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can map entities to SPs in EF 6.0 http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/03/01/whats-new-in-entity-framework-6.aspx

Comment: Its about CRUD operitions i want for select

Comment: Right. As long as you correctly map it to an entity, you should be able to query for objects directly from the DbContext. All CRUD operations should work.